# Scifi horror on spaceship/station with killer robot

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots, space, horror

This is going to sound ridiculous because I remember so little of it, but when I was a kid (<10) I remember seeing this movie where these people are stuck on a spaceship or space station and are being hunted down and killed by some kind of robot, at least I think it was a robot. I know in the end they manage to get away in an escape pod or something but that's basically all I remember.

I don't think it's Saturn 3, but I could be wrong...

Comment: How many people? Adults, children? Men and women? Man in suit robot or puppet? Wardrobe of people? American / British / other? When were you < 10?

Comment: Could this be Disney's [The Black Hole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzUJJKDa558)? - Killer robot, check, escape pod, check

Comment: How long ago were you a kid?

Comment: This question describes probably 100 movies, as well as plenty of episodes from Outer Limits, Star Trek, etc.  I think it should be closed...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - I'm reasonably sure I've exhausted the most obvious matches below. Feel free to add any more.

Comment: I notice that the question says that the people are both hunted down and killed and manage to get away in an escape pod.  Does that not narrow things down somewhat to the whole _zombies in an escape pod_ genre?  Anyway, I'm sure that you've missed two obvious matches.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: This! I’m in the same situation, I remember seeing a film when I was a kid, a few people were on a space station and there was a robot trying to kill them, he was helping a girl to get some stuff out from here eye. It’s deffo Saturn 3.

Answer (score 23):

Could this be the low-budget B-movie "[Star Wars](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/)"?

In a scene near the start, several people on a spaceship are attacked by a large cyborg. Several of the crew then use an escape pod.

[image]

Comment: Har Har Har funny

Answer (score 11):

The description is very vague, but it reminds me of "[The Black Hole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzUJJKDa558)" a 1979 Disney-movie (no, not a funny one).

Please check the movie description to see if it's the one you're looking for or provide more details.

Answer (score 10):

Could this be [Saturn 3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079285)? Killer robot, space station, escape pod.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Could this be "[Space Truckers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Truckers)"? Spaceship, killer robots aplenty, escape pods

Answer (score 6):

Could this be [Android](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083557) (1982)? - Space station, killer robots, escape pods, etc.

Comment: Are you trying to make a (very humorous) point @Richard?

Comment: @Jim2B - I was tempted to close as "too broad" but I realised that the list of films that fit is actually relatively small. I decided to simply cover all the bases.

Comment: @Jim2B:
I suspect we are learning just how Richard has acquired so much rep... :-P

Comment: @SeanDuggan - When your target is wide, use a shotgun.

Comment: VHS RIP indeed.

Answer (score 5):

As I noted in a comment above, Richard has cast his net far too narrowly.

### What decade was the questioner <10?

For starters, who is to say that the questioner was "<10" in the 1970s?  Xe could have been a kid in the 1960s, in which case xe is obviously talking about the well-known horror movie *2001: A Space Odyssey*.  It has non-human killers:
[image: Killers from the movie 2001]
They silently get aboard a space station after a while:
[image: Descendents of the killers getting into a space station in the movie 2001]
And at the end of the movie, one of them leaves in an escape pod so that there is room for a sequel where he comes back to terrorize again, with more pods and that bloke from another 1970s B-movie franchise:

### Not necessarily a robot or an escape pod,then ?

Even setting aside the questioner's restriction to just the *zombies in an escape pod* genre of horror films, I note that the questioner qualified the question with:

> I think it was a robot

So it might have been an alien.

Of course, the archetype killer-alien-on-spaceship-escape-pod story is of course "[Rimmerworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rimmerworld)" from iconic horror-comedy television series *Red Dwarf*.  (This is not the only such story in *Red Dwarf*.  In the episode "[Polymorph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorph_(Red_Dwarf_episode))" the creature aboard ship is a shape-changer, just like in *2001*.)  But the questioner was pretty sure, at least *more* sure than xe was that a robot and an escape pod were involved, that this was a movie.

So we might want to also consider movies that parodied *Red Dwarf*.  One particular parody comes to mind because its attempt to be warm and lighthearted utterly failed.  The director made several mistakes, including the one of changing the Rimmer character into a woman:

[image]

And getting [Kryten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryten) *completely wrong*:
[image: Ridley Scott's poor attempt at Kryten]

### "or something"

Of course, if the questioner were also unsure that it was even a movie, we of course immediately think of the escape-pods in *The Hitch-Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy* radio series, which ate Zaphod Beeblebrox in a spaceship, or something:

> **ASSISTANT ARCTURAN PILOT:** That Haggunennon ate you. How did you escape?
>
> **ZAPHOD:** Ha-ha-ho, no problem. It was a super-evolving species right?
>
> **ASSISTANT ARCTURAN PILOT:** Yes.
>
> **ZAPHOD:** It ate me whilst it was playing at being the Ravenous Bugblatter Beast of Traal. And then like, seconds later, made the mistake of re-evolving into a really neat little escape capsule.
>
> **ASSISTANT ARCTURAN PILOT:** It evolved into an escape capsule?!
>
> **ZAPHOD:** Yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the kubrik one : [2001: A Space Odyssey](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062622/).

Comment: Never heard of it.

Comment: That's strange, it's well known.

Answer (score 1):

It could be [Project Shadowchaser III](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114192/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) aka Shadowchaser III, Project Shadowchaser 3000 and Edge Of Darkness from 1995.

It seems to match all the criteria, it might just be too recent (depending on the askers age).

You can watch the movie here

Answer (score -2):

This could be the 1974 film titled `Dark Star`. These guys are stuck on a ship in space with this weird robot creature that looked like a big blow up beach-ball that was trying to kill them. Eventually they destroy it and it deflates.

Throughout the film the crew also have to talk the ship's AI out of self-destructing, however all fails, the ship self destructs and the remainder of the crew are left floating off though space.

Comment: As @Richard has pointed out, this question resembles the broad side of a barn. And yet by citing a film in which the crew is *not* being killed, *not* by a robot and do *not* get away in an escape pod, you have... missed it.